# Как сделать круг в IE8, если очень надо?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Собственно, речь о стилизации радиобаттонов и чекбоксов. Радиобаттон должен быть круглым, но в IE8 `border-radius` не работает.

Вариант включать обводку в фоновую картинку не подходит, поскольку нужны обводки разных цветов в зависимости от условий.

Какие есть альтернативы?

```css
input[type="radio"], input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

input[type="radio"] + label, input[type="checkbox"] + label {
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
}

input[type="radio"] + label {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label {
  border-radius: .25em;
}

input:checked + label {
  background: silver; /* На самом деле тут фоновая картинка, разная */
}
```

```html
<input type=radio name=r id=r1><label for=r1 onclick=""></label>
<input type=radio name=r id=r2><label for=r2 onclick=""></label>
<input type=radio name=r id=r3><label for=r3 onclick=""></label>
<input type=radio name=r id=r4><label for=r4 onclick=""></label>
<br>
<input type=checkbox name=c id=c1><label for=c1 onclick=""></label>
<input type=checkbox name=c id=c2><label for=c2 onclick=""></label>
<input type=checkbox name=c id=c3><label for=c3 onclick=""></label>
<input type=checkbox name=c id=c4><label for=c4 onclick=""></label>
```

PS: Вместо `:checked` скрипт вешает соответствующий класс.

Comment: Отсутствие кавычек у параметров атрибутов оскорбляет мою религию :)

Comment: @tutankhamun 1. это же пример. 2. этот код валидный.

Comment: 1. Ну я смайлик поставил тоже не просто так; 2. Это я понимаю и отличаю html от xml. Просто глаз режет. Это видимо только мои тараканы (как например, стараюсь не делать тело if без фигурных скобок, даже когда можно)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дикая, конечно, идея: в IE8 прекрасно работает vml. Можно внутрь `label` поместить `vml:shape` и стилизовать уже его.

Answer (score 4):

Для IE8 должен действовать принцип деградации! Не нужно пытаться сделать пиксель перфект в этом древнем браузере, это лишняя и никому не нужная работа. Если у вас включен IE8 в список поддерживаемых продуктов, то это означает что в нем просто должно всё работать, пусть и без экстра красивостей, но просто должно.

Поймите так же следующее, попытки все красиво стилизовать в IE8 приведут только к тому, что этот браузер (и так медленный и древний) получит еще одну тормозящую фичу. Так же вспомните что в 99% случаев, IE8 запускается отнюдь не в вашей быстрой виртуальной машине, а на каком-то древнем, даже реликтовом компе, который и одну вкладку еле тянет. Пользователи таких компов сегодня радуются просто тому, что сайт вообще открылся как-то, и им даже можно пользоваться.

UPD.
Если всё же очень нужно нарисовать, то всё равно, лучше делать это картинкой. Я помню что у вас несколько цветов, но тут можно схитрить, скажем сделав одну белую прозрачную картинку с круглой дырочкой в центре. Это позволит менять цвета через CSS.

Comment: IE8 нужен по другим причинам, не ради пользователей. Отказаться от него нельзя никак. В целом против деградации ничего не имею, но тут она немного не к месту. Чекбоксы будут квадратными без скруглений - ok, но одинаковый внешний вид чекбокса и радиобаттона - это уже ужас - надо как-то скруглять радиобаттон.

Comment: Про картинку с дыркой - интересная идея.

Comment: Фича в том, что для IE8 можно вернуть нативные радио батоны.

Comment: Помню я их нативные под IE8 - там тоже не фонтан со стилизацией. А незаполненные обязательные поля и некорректные комбинации помечать как-то надо.

Comment: Боюсь, на реликтовом компьютере IE8 не взлетит. Поэтому если оно работает, можно его грузить по полной :)