# Как стилизовать чекбокс в зависимости от того, выбран он или нет?

Tags: html, css, css3, checkbox

Не выбранный:

```
<input type="radio" id="edit-attributes-field-width-935--4" name="attributes[field_width]" value="935" class="form-radio ajax-processed">
```

Выбранный:

```
<input type="radio" id="edit-attributes-field-width-935--3" name="attributes[field_width]" value="935" checked="checked" class="form-radio ajax-processed">
```

Comment: А ответ принять не пора?

Answer (score 1):

```css
input[type="radio"], input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

input[type="radio"] + label, input[type="checkbox"] + label {
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
}

input[type="radio"] + label {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label {
  border-radius: .25em;
}

input:checked + label {
  background: silver; /* На самом деле тут фоновая картинка, разная */
}
```

```html
<input type=radio name=r id=r1><label for=r1 onclick=""></label>
<input type=radio name=r id=r2><label for=r2 onclick=""></label>
<input type=radio name=r id=r3><label for=r3 onclick=""></label>
<input type=radio name=r id=r4><label for=r4 onclick=""></label>
<br>
<input type=checkbox name=c id=c1><label for=c1 onclick=""></label>
<input type=checkbox name=c id=c2><label for=c2 onclick=""></label>
<input type=checkbox name=c id=c3><label for=c3 onclick=""></label>
<input type=checkbox name=c id=c4><label for=c4 onclick=""></label>
```

Comment: Код из моего вопроса http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/450928/178988

Comment: без приобразований в коде html документа никак? Мой код выглядит так:`<label class="option art-radiobutton" for="edit-attributes-field-width-935--2"><input type="radio" id="edit-attributes-field-width-935--2" name="attributes[field_width]" value="935" class="form-radio ajax-processed">
 300  </label>`

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов, input внутри лейбла можно, но всё равно придётся после него `span` положить. Псевдоэлементы не работают с input'ом, а псевдокласс не применим к родителю, так что надо менять что-то.

Comment: Тогда беда, псеводэлементы конечно было бы отлично...

Comment: в идеале было бы написать проверку скриптом, и стилизовтаь оберточный lable, но к сожалению после выбора радиоприемники, весь lable через ajax перезагружается, думал сделать проверку по клику, но после клика идет перезагрузка, элемента, и вся моя проверка коту под хвост