# Стилизация radio button

Tags: javascript, html, css

Возможно ли сделать radio button, чтобы были не "кружками", а вместо них мои изображения?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/450928/178988

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
input[type="radio"]{display: none;}

label{ width: 30px; height: 30px; display: inline-block; }

label.bla1{background: url("http://bbcsproducts.com/carsharing//public_html/uploads/preferences/1453751767_90404.jpg") center no-repeat; width: 50px; height: 50px; }

input[type="radio"]:checked+label{
    border: black solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="bla1" value="bla1" id="bla1"/>
<label for="bla1" class="bla1"></label>
```